# I'm forced to restart Rails Server to update modifications in controller because of Chrome

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-chrome, lsof

Normaly, I don't need to restart rails s when I modify something in controller. But now it doesn't longer work. If I only want to add a "puts" line, I need to kill the server, kill Chrome then restart all, it makes me lose a lot of time.

In fact, when I kill rails s and I launch `lsof -wni tcp:3000`
I still get chrome as:

```
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
chrome  2112 leon  250u  IPv6  84701      0t0  TCP [::1]:59116->[::1]:3000 (CLOSE_WAIT)
chrome  2112 leon  275u  IPv6  80767      0t0  TCP [::1]:59080->[::1]:3000 (CLOSE_WAIT)
```

Comment: killing chrome won't help reloading Rails. You probably only need to restart rails.

Comment: But you shouldn't even restart rails.. Rails hot-reloading would auto reload. How do u start your rails server? is it via `rails serve`?

Comment: Have you tried just refreshing the chrome browser and checking your serve logs for the puts you insert?

Comment: @songyy I start it with rails s

Comment: @Mark yes, it doesn't change anything...

Comment: Do you work on MacOS? I had some weird problems like yours on Mojave with another Macbook… they went away on their own, after I tried a lot of things without success